# Flex 4 Spark List setting scroll position

Tags: apache-flex, list, scroll, position

How can I set the scroll position for a Spark List control please?

Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found a solution:

You set either horizontalScrollPosition or verticalScrollPosition for the layout of the List control, not the List control itself.

e.g.

MXML
`<s:TileLayout id="listLayout" verticalScrollPosition="30"/>`

AS3
`listLayout.verticalScrollPosition=30;`

Comment: Well, we should at least meet once before talking marriage and other things.